# Ruby debugging: How to find out which method or variable is responding?

Tags: ruby, pry

When debugging ruby code with some complexity, it is easy to get confused by stacked method definitions, and by naming conflicts with local variables.

**I am looking for a fast way to find out which method or variable responds to an expression**, something like `any_expression.identify`.

The best I could find so far is:

```
method(:happy)
#=> #<Method: Object(Helper)#happy>

method(:happy).source_location
#=> ["/home/somebody/project/lib/helper.rb", 9]
```

Unfortunately a local variable (like `happy=42`) will precede, but `method(:happy)` will still return the other method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to prefix with `self.class.new`. It wouldn't work if the class doesn't have constructor with no arguments anyway.

```
local_variables.include?(:foo) # local variable
method(:foo)                   # method
```

---

Another alternative is to use the `defined?` keyword:

```
foo = 42
def bar; end

defined?(foo) # => "local-variable"
defined?(bar) # => "method"
```

---

In pry, you can use `show-method`:

```
show-method bar # =>
  # From: (pry) @ line 104:
  # Owner: Object
  # Visibility: public
  # Number of lines: 1

  # def bar; end
```

And `ls`:

```
ls foo # =>
  # Comparable#methods: between?
  # Numeric#methods: 
  #   +@      conj       imaginary     pretty_print_cycle  rectangular           
  #   abs2    conjugate  nonzero?      quo                 remainder             
  #   angle   eql?       phase         real                singleton_method_added
  #   arg     i          polar         real?               step                  
  #   coerce  imag       pretty_print  rect                to_c                  
  # Integer#methods: 
  #   ceil         downto  gcdlcm    next       pred         times   to_r    
  #   chr          floor   integer?  numerator  rationalize  to_i    truncate
  #   denominator  gcd     lcm       ord        round        to_int  upto    
  # Fixnum#methods: 
  #   %  **  -@  <<   ==   >=  ^           div     fdiv       modulo  succ  zero?
  #   &  +   /   <=   ===  >>  abs         divmod  inspect    odd?    to_f  |    
  #   *  -   <   <=>  >    []  bit_length  even?   magnitude  size    to_s  ~
```

---

I don't think there is a way to check exactly where a local variable was defined. However, you could always reverse search in your console to see the line that defined it:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>: `foo =` => *(reverse-i-search)`foo =': foo = 42*

Comment: Great answer. I removed `self.class.new.` from the question.

Comment: `defined?` and `show-method` together provide all I was looking for. Ideally there would be a command combining the two.

Comment: @bogl, there is not (AFAIK). Happy you found it useful though. (:

Answer (score 3):

Use `owner`. It gives the module where a method is defined.

```
class A
  def foo; end
end

class B < A
end

B.new.method(:foo).owner # => A
```